# C++ Overloading -> operator, how does it work?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was trying to implement a smart pointer class similar to the standard library auto_ptr and accordingly I had to overload the -> operator for the same. Here is my code

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr
{

   T * operator -> ()
  {
    return _pAct;
  }

 private:
 T * _pAct;
};
```

Rest of the implementation is not shown so as to avoid diversion from my query.

Now I create a SmartPtr of class A and call a method Show() present in A on it :

```
SmartPtr smPtr(new A);
smPtr->Show();
```

Here is my query(don't know if its valid also)

Since SmartPtr::operator->() return A*, the call to show should translate to (A*)Show. Why it translates to (A*)->Show() ?

or in other words how does smPtr->Show() mean call Show() on whatever smPtr->() operator returns ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because operator `->` applies sequentially until it can't be applied any more.

#### 13.5.6 Class member access [over.ref]

> 1) `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no
>   parameters. It implements class member access using `->
>   postfix-expression -> id-expression` **An expression `x->m` is interpreted
>   as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if
>   `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best
>   match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).** (emphasis mine)

Which means, in your case, it translates to:

```
smPtr.operator->()->Show();
          |           |
      returns A*   call Show on the A*
```